# curl and wget not working with https sites after upgrade to ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: wget, https, curl, openssl, ubuntu-18.04

Seems to be a openssl related issue. Anyone have any ideas as to what this is?

Note that the url works in a browser.

With wget:

```
# wget -d https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x

DEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.4 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/user/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'setup_8.x' (UTF-8) -> 'setup_8.x' (UTF-8)
--2018-09-02 19:54:06--  https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x
Could not seed PRNG; consider using --random-file.
OpenSSL: error:2406F07A:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Not a regular file
Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.
```

With curl:

```
# curl -v -L https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x

*   Trying 205.251.207.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to deb.nodesource.com (205.251.207.2) port 443 (#0)

<hangs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=227

> When using wget with https, if you get the following error:
>
> ```
> Could not seed PRNG; consider using --random-file.
> Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.
> ```
>
> It means that the udev daemon may be in physical mode.   Create the
>   /dev/random device manually:
>
> ```
> mknod /dev/random c 1 8
> ```

Comment: Yes, saw that. Doesn't work. The already exists.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. What if you purge openssl then install it again? And can you please update your original question with the version number of curl, wget and openssl?

Comment: Tried that too.